# Dev Express Tab Control refresh

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I'm using dev express tools for a project.  I have a form with a TabControl. Each tab has a gridcontrol/gridview that has specific data.

When i first load the form on the default tab I bind the grid to a specific data programatically.

```
bindingsource = stored_proc_select_all_data.
```

> This could be ID, Firstname, LastName etc.

I then want to Hide ID from the gridview, so the method "form1_shown" gets called to redisplay the grid to hide the column

```
view1.Columns.Item("ID").Visible = False
```

This works for tab 1 that is displayed by default but when i click on tab2 that has a grid with data it will not hide the ID for this grid.

```
view2.Columns.Item("ID").Visible = False
```

this code is also in the form1_shown event. How can i get the ID to hide or somehow redisplay the form on tab2 that would work properly? thanks

They have two different binding sources. 
Upon form load i have this

```
`BindingSourceGroups.DataSource = storedproc_selectallgroups`
`BindingSourceUsers.DataSource = Storedproc_selectallusers`
```

Now both grids do get populated on both tabs.

But if i want to hide a column grammatically, even on tab 1 that loads by default i still have to put this code `GridViewGroups.Columns.Item("ID").Visible = False` in the `Form_shown event` otherwise it won't even work.
and it definitely doesn't work to hide the id of gridviewusers on tab2

Comment: are you sharing the same `BindingSource` for the 2 different Gridview controls..? if so this could be the issue.. or do you have auto generate columns set = true..? can you show what both gridview controls look like..?

Comment: no different binding sources, updated answer

Comment: you mean updated `Question` don't you..?

Comment: yes obviously it was a mistake

Comment: figured it out by just activating all the tabs upon form load first.... stupid fix

Answer (score 0):

in WPF you ca hide with the property in Xaml

```
Visibility="Hidden"
```

in windows Form

You can manage the visibility of the corresponding GridView's columns via the  "GridColumn.Visible" property value.